# Complex Number question [Cauchy Integral/Series]

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, complex-integration

I'm going through the practice finals that my professor uploaded on his site, and I came across this question, and I have absolutely no one clue how to approach it and never seen anything like this on the assignments.[There are no solutions, he said he will be uploading them next week but I also have get prepared for other final exams as well.] So I'm just asking for hint to approach the question and ill make sure if my answer is correct next week. 
Thank you all your help.

Heres the question
[image]

Solution:
[image]

Comment: Well, I think that you have a clue. A very big one, as a matter of fact.

Comment: I couldn't get to any solution with the hint, which is why i asked for some help

Comment: Bound the integral (for $n \geq 3$) on the right by something and let $R \to \infty$. Notice that the left hand side is independent of $R$.

Comment: Check out the solution I have uploaded. and please let me know if its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\ge3$.  Note that on the contour $C$ we have $|z|=R$ and so $|f(z)|\le R^2$.  Using the integral formula you are given, together with the $LM$ estimation lemma,
$$|f^{(n)}(0)|\le \frac{n!}{2\pi}(2\pi R)\frac{R^2}{R^{n+1}}
  =\frac{n!}{R^{n-2}}\ .$$
Since $f$ is entire, this works for any radius $R$, so we can let $R\to\infty$ and then we get. . . ?

Comment: So the limit will equal 0.
Then I did taylor series expansion, am I on the right track? I shall upload a picture.

Comment: I have uploaded an solution, please let me know if there is any mistake

Comment: I'm on a small screen and it's a bit hard to read, but as far as I can see it looks good.